# How do I investigate the memory Usage?

Tags: ram, command-line

I've a Micromax A74 with (rooted) Android 4.2.2. Recently I've faced the crashing of some application and started to analyze the usage of RAM.

Settings>Apps>Running is not helpful:

[image: screenshot]

Sometimes I found only 2 MB free!

**I want to know which applications are consuming the memory?**

I've also tried `top -n 1 -m 8`:

[image: screenshot]

But I can't figure out the top applications which cause for lowering the RAM.

On GNU/Linux I can run `top -n 1 -o %MEM` which displays the applications that consuming most of RAM but such feature isn't available with `/system/bin/top` or `busybox top`.

So, How do investigate which applications are consuming a lot of memory? so-that I can force-stop them.

<sup>Note: Don't suggest any app like ram booster, it is the different question.</sup>

Comment: What does `adb shell dumpsys meminfo` tell you? See if this document helps: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html

Comment: @Firelord `error: device not found`. I don't have any connection to PC with my Android phone. I want to investigate using phone only. If you've any helpful solution/suggestion, you can post an answer.

Comment: Do you've root access? Do `su -c 'dumpsys meminfo'` in that case.

Comment: @Firelord http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27726834#27726834

Answer (score -1):

It seems you wanna order by ram usage, I believe that is

```
top -n 1 -m 25 -s rss
```

But I get it from your question. Thanks.